# How does the accelerometer in Unity 2d work?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to make a ball moving with accelerometer, I watched a lot of videos about it but it didn't work with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple. Just add `Rigidbody2D` on your ball game object. then use this code:

```
private Rigidbody2D rigid;
private Vector2 movement;
public float movementSpeed = 10f;

void Start()
{
  rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update()
{
  movement = new Vector2(Input.acceleration.x , Input.acceleration.y) * movementSpeed;
  rigid.AddForce(movement);
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: thank you  it work with me but how can make the move more real like 8ball

Comment: You're welcome. You can use `Physics Material` to set static friction, dynamic friction, bounciness and other options to make the ball's move more real

Comment: Pleasure helping you :)